# Matlab match a string with regular expression

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I need to process user input as string with Matlab. I know exactly how the allowed string can look like, but i don't know how to use regular expressions to check for valid strings. I would like to return `true` for valid input strings and `false` otherwise.

Valid inputs start with letter `s` or `b` followed by a blank space and then contain a number from 1 to 20. Examples for valid strings read as follows:

```
's 14'
'b 7'
'b 20'
```

Examples for invalid strings read as follows:

```
's 24' % number too large
's14' % missing space
'x 13' % wrong letter
'b 111' % number too large / also 3 digits for the number, where only 1 to 2 are allowed.
```

I started with this line of code, which seems to be close to a solution but not quite:

```
regexp('s 26', '[sb] [1-20]', 'match')
```

It does not work out, as it sees `s 2` as a positive match, but in reality the input is `s 26` which is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?:s|b)\s(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)$
```

try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/14

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. Can you explain your thoughts on this please?

Comment: Is it: [1-9]|1[0-9]|20: either any of 1-9 OR a fixed 1 concatenated with any 1-9 OR 20?

Comment: @Nras it is either `1-9` or `10-19` or `20`.